# Geopandas with df

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have dataframe containing `location, side_a, and side_b`, which are countries that particpate in wars.
I also have details such as number of death, start year and so on for each war.

Assuming I want to present the number of death in each state using geopandas, how do I do so?
I've tries to use this code but it just gave me a graph of the world (column = death number):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]
world[column] = df[column]
world.plot(column=column, ax=ax, legend=True)
```

For exemaple, I want this df to beacome a graph where all states are colored:

| war_index | location | death number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India, China | 20 |
| 2 | India | 10 |

Then China will be colerd in one color that stand for 10, India other color stand for 30
and the rest wont be colored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to add a column to `world` with the number of deaths. So first you would need to calculate the total number of deaths in `df` per country. You can do this by splitting the strings in `location`. Then exploding that column and running a `groupby` on that column. Subsequently you can use `pd.merge` to merge the dataframes on name/location, then plot `world` by `death number`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([ { "war_index": 1, "location": "India, China", "death number": 20 }, { "war_index": 2, "location": "India", "death number": 10 } ])
df['location'] = df['location'].str.split(', ')
df = df.explode('location').groupby('location').agg('sum').reset_index()

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]
world = pd.merge(world,df[['location','death number']], left_on='name', right_on='location', how='left')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
world.plot(column='death number', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

Result:

[image]

If you also want to show the rest of the world, you can replace `nan` in the column `death number` with 0.

```
world['death number'] = world['death number'].fillna(0)
```

[image]